# Random staged files spontaneously appear in git workdir

Tags: git

I use `git-new-workdir` to separate my work areas (Git version is 2.1.2, `git-worktree` is not available). I keep one cloned copy of the repository (which I know the workdirs point to via symbolic links). As I work over time, random files I have never touched spontaneously appear staged in the cloned directory (which I don't have to touch for this to happen), and sometimes in associated workdirs. Many such files appear and they are always staged (these files are legitimate repository objects, i.e., they aren't completely random garbage). I have been unable to find a rhyme or reason to it except that usually the workdirs that I care about are unaffected; it only seems to affect directories I don't frequently use. This has been going on for months.

Sample work sequence:

1. `git clone` of repository (did this once) -- call it "repo"
2. Create a work area:`git-new-workdir repo TICKET`; `cd TICKET`; `git fetch`; `git
   co branch`
3. Work on ticket, edit, commit, push files, fetch, pull; I may or may not switch branches, usually not
4. Create another work area; work on it
5. Rinse, repeat
6. Time passes: Switch back and forth, do more commits, pushes, fetches, and pulls, delete workdirs
7. Go to "repo", do `git status`; a bunch of staged files appear, including new, modified, and deleted files, completely unrelated to anything I've done anywhere (again, not garbage, but they appear to be actual changes to legitimate repo objects that somehow got propagated to my workdir). No merge is indicated, although it looks similar to what one sees in the middle of a merge. It looks like I've modified repo files and done a `git add`, but I haven't.

I'm sort of stuck when this happens; either I leave it alone for fear that "fixing" it will break something, or I delete the whole directory and start again (if it's a workdir).

My only theory is that perhaps git doesn't like it if I delete a workdir that I've used without its permission. But I see no `git-del-workdir` command.

Any tips for isolating this or ideas shedding light on the situation would be appreciated; I haven't come up with any ideas so far. While I've used git for a few years, my knowledge of git is fairly narrow. I do see that `git-new-workdir` has been replaced with `git worktree`; is this one of the reasons why?

While I've tried to search SO or the Internet, it's difficult because it's hard to come up with effective keywords for the symptoms. I realize my writeup is somewhat wanting but it's hard to replicate this problem on a small scale because that would require creating my own repo which I don't have the means of doing (and also would require investing a lot of possibly fruitless time and effort).

Environment is rhel6 AWS.

EDIT: I have determined that in affected directories, the differences appear to be reversals of what's been recently checked in, presumably since I last did a pull on the workdir. Added files show up as deleted, deleted files show up as added, and modified files are reversed. This would be consistent with the theory that some index is getting messed up.

FAQ

1. Why are you running Git version 2.1.2? A: Because that's what my organization supplies and I am but a lowly leaf node.
2. Why don't you compile 2.18.0 from source? A: 1) I am not sure of the interoperability implications. 2) I work on VMs which I spin up at the beginning of each day (or several times a day) and terminate at the end. It's a pain to install non-standard software. If I could produce an RPM to install that would help. I'm not real keen on doing a "make install" every morning.

Comment: Can you add some detail around, "a bunch of staged files appear, including new, modified, and deleted files, completely unrelated to anything I've done anywhere"? I'm guessing these aren't random data in random files. As an aside, I would definitely use `git worktree` today for this kind of thing.

Comment: Can we assume that you aren't using submodules and you aren't using any hooks?

Comment: Thanks, @Chris, I added some additional clarifying details. The files are legitimate repo objects, not garbage. It looks similar to what might happen if I were in the middle of a merge of mainline changes into my workdir, except there is no merge indication and I did no merge. It would be interesting to try to relate the changes that show up to specific commits.

Comment: Hmm, @K.A.Buhr, I don't know what a submodule is, but I am using hooks provided by my organization. I looked at these for anything suspicious, but mostly they check for debug indicators in the code, enforcing ticket number norms, updating cscope, benign stuff like that.

Comment: I have not used the old `git-new-workdir` scripts but they play tricks with links and the (singular) index file that Git uses. If the tricks go wrong you'll have different work trees clobbering each others' index file, which will result in the symptoms you are seeing. You'd be better off using separate clones, which should sidestep the issue, but obviously will use more space.